# Timeline if 0.5 millimetres= 1.5 years how many millimetres would equal 1 year

Tags: arithmetic

Hi I am working on a timeline and know that 0.5 millimetres equals 1.5 years how many millimetres would equal a year thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$
0.5\text{ mm}=1.5\text{ years}.
$$
Now divide both sides by $1.5$, we will obtain
\begin{align}
\frac{0.5\text{ mm}}{1.5}&=\frac{1.5\text{ years}}{1.5}\\
\large\color{blue}{\frac13\text{ mm}}&\large\color{blue}{=1\text{ years}}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac{0.5 \mathrm{mm}}{1.5 \mathrm{y}} \cdot \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{1.5}}{\dfrac{1}{1.5}} = \dfrac{\dfrac{0.5}{1.5} \mathrm{mm}}{1 \mathrm{y}} = \dfrac{\dfrac13 \mathrm{mm}}{1 \mathrm{y}}$$